# Problem updating an array with an object of Arrays

Tags: php

I am running into some issues updating and inserting an Array. As background i run a  Compare by using lukascivil / TreeWalker to see what the changes are between 2 docs and then i save them to my doc.

This is the object i am trying to push into my Changes Array

```
Array
(
    [new] => Array
        (
        )

    [removed] => Array
        (
        )

    [edited] => Array
        (
            [Address/StreetName] => Array
                (
                    [oldvalue] => Vista Des
                    [newvalue] => Vista De Dons
                )

            [Address/StateOrProvince] => Array
                (
                    [oldvalue] => TX
                    [newvalue] => CA
                )

        )

)
```

The above is $r in my code and this is how i try to push it i get from the following above $r a object of edited with multiple objects in it. Instead i want edited to be an array with multiple objects in it. What do i need to change that ?

```
array_push($baseRecord['Changes'], $r);


{
      "new": [],
      "removed": [],
      "edited": {
        "Address/StreetName": {
          "oldvalue": "Vista Des",
          "newvalue": "Vista De Dons"
        },
        "Address/StateOrProvince": {
          "oldvalue": "TX",
          "newvalue": "CA"
        }
      }
    }
```

This is what it should look like and it has before moving from 7.0 to 7.4

```
{
"Changes" : [
        {"id": "1234-123456-1234" , "EditTime" : "2022-03-17T17:43:20.855531-07:00",
        "new" :[],
        "removed" : [] ,
        "edited" : [{
            "oldvalue": "Vistaons",
            "newvalue": "Vista De Dons"
        },
        {
            "oldvalue": "(BP)",
            "newvalue": "Bluff Area Properties (BP)"
        }]
        }
]   
    
}
```

this is what is saved in JSON

```
{
  "Changes": [
    {
      "new": [],
      "removed": [],
      "edited": {
        "MLSAreaMajor": {
          "oldvalue": "CB - rano Beach",
          "newvalue": "CB - Capistrano Beach"
        },
        "Address/StreetName": {
          "oldvalue": "Vista ons",
          "newvalue": "Vista De Dons"
        },
        "Address/City": {
          "oldvalue": "Daoint",
          "newvalue": "Dana Point"
        }
      },
      "id": "30633f37-0548-472a-a8ea-e409257f3637",
      "changeDateTime": "2022-03-17 18:17:46"
    }
  ],
  "DocId": "Residential::a77ccc9c-82d0-4c0f-b873-055757fc171d"
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain... I have the return from the Tree Walker and you can see that the print_r of $ r shows that [edited] => Array. My question is why does it end up with {} for the array of edited ?

Comment: Based on reading array_merge is not applicable, as i have the Changes array which is an array empty or one or more objects that hold a arrays, and i want to push the result into it as a new object which works but instead of edited[] i have edited{}

Comment: If i understand your point well, The {} is for array. When you put an object into parent array the result will be like: `{[object],[object]}`. If you want remove `{}` you can convert your array to object.

Comment: I just updated the original question, when I save the $r to my Array this is what it looks. IN JSON an Array is [{object} , {object}] not array { {object} , {object}}